# Trying to find a good interpolation technique

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, interpolation, smoothing

I am currently attempting to interpolate a large set of X and Y values using Python. The arrays are quite long (6 million values), and I am trying to extend that to 10 million values. Given my problem, the interpolation should not go above or below the minimum/maximum values of Y. So to do this, I wrote a function to perform an inverse distance weighted (IDW) interpolation. However, it just takes way too long (10 days at least) to complete. I used the IDW because the data is also kinda noisy, and by setting the p-value to < 1.0 it effectively smooths it a bit. Here is the function I wrote:

```
def idw_simple(x, y, x_new, p):
    # interpolate 2D data using inverse distance weighted technique
    y_new = np.array([])

    for i in x_new:
        # Calc. distance for each x_new-value from every x-value 
        min_array = np.abs(x - i)
        min_array_sorted = np.sort(min_array)

        # Find 10 closest x-values 
        near_indices = [int(np.where(min_array == k)[0]) for k in min_array_sorted[:10]]

        # Calc. y_new based on nearby weighted points
        near_indices = np.sort(near_indices)
        weights = 1 / (min_array[near_indices] ** p)
        y_new = np.append(y_new, np.sum(weights * y[near_indices]) / weights.sum())

    return y_new
```

If anyone has an idea of either how to speed it up OR if there is another interpolation technique you think would provide similar results, I would love to hear what people think.

Comment: If the interpolation values have to be between ymin and ymax, why have you not considering linear interpolation? Oh because of the noise, is it?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi Yeah the noise, linear would definitely be faster but the results are less ideal.

Answer (score 1):

If the input data is sorted in increasing order of `x`, you can do the "10 nearest points" step *much* more efficiently. Before the loop initialize `j = 0`, then at the top of your `i` loop body do

```
while j < len(x) - 10 and abs(x[j+10] - i) < abs(x[j] - i):
    j = j + 1
```

and then `x[j:j+10]` and `y[j:j+10]` will be the 10 nearest points to `i` in each loop iteration, *without* the need to sort and filter 10-million-element lists every time around. This should be many times faster.

Comment: Thank you @hobbs,  I thought about doing that at first but the only thing is that the original x-values are not linearly spaced, so the 10 closest may be all greater than x_new in one iteration but the opposite in the next. I'll try it and see if it's too unreasonable or not to assume a set window.

Comment: @Patrick as far as I can see, the point selection shouldn't be any different from what you have currently, so if that's a concern, it's the same concern for both of them :)